# JFrame accessing Data from the database not showing

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jframe, windowbuilder

I have other classes which perform the task of retrieving the data. I want my jframe to show them but there is a big problem somewhere which causes the program to show blank page!!
Here is the Code:

```
package mySystem;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;

public class DisplayCustomers extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static Connection con;
    private static ArrayList<Customer> customers;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> name;
    private ArrayList<JLabel> sureName;
    private ArrayList<JButton> accept;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://my_url", 
                            "user", "pass");
                    Item item = new Item(1987,con);
                    customers = LookUp.findCustomers(item.getId(), con);
                    DisplayCustomers frame = new DisplayCustomers(customers,item,con);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (SQLException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DisplayCustomers(ArrayList<Customer> customers,Item item,Connection con) 
            throws SQLException {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 583, 409);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(customers.size(), 4, 2, 5));

        name = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        sureName = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        accept = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        Customer buff = null;

        for(int i=0;i < customers.size();i++) {
            buff = customers.get(i); // for the sake of readability

            name.add(new JLabel(buff.getName()));
            sureName.add(new JLabel(buff.getSureName()));
            String butMsg = "Accept";
            if(buff.isValid())
                butMsg = "Customer is invlid";
            accept.add(new JButton(butMsg));
            contentPane.add(name.get(i));
            contentPane.add(sureName.get(i));
            contentPane.add(accept.get(i));


        }
        con.close();


    }
    public void displayError(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 583, 409);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        JLabel error = new JLabel("Exception Thrown");
        contentPane.add(error);
    }
}
```

I keep running this using windowbuilder but the button says it's not compiling and it's only previewing the window. So I'm not sure how to properly run it! Also when I placed new Connection inside the constructor it kept giving error about driver not found even though it has been added as .jar file to my build path and every other non Jframe class runs fine. This is my first time using Jframe and it's giving me a really hard time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `"This is my first time using Jframe and it's giving me a really hard time."` -- this won't answer your question, but I recommend that you not use a Windows Builder utility until you first learn the rudiments of the Swing library. It's hard enough to use the library, it's harder still to use it with a tool if you don't yet understand it. Go through the tutorials and learn it first. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: I actually didn't use the design part at all! I just wrote the code. It's a very simple code. For every row in the database I wanna add a row here! how hard can that be?

Comment: *"Also when I placed new Connection inside the constructor it kept giving error about driver not found even though it has been added as .jar file to my build path"* I'd trying to resolve this issue first

Comment: I did solve it. By placing Connection in `main()` . Now no exception is throw which means connection runs fine.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: I found another error. If I just run it the way I run console applications it works like a charm but as soon as I click on design button I am unable to run it that way and preview won't work at all :(

Comment: I have fixed my problem by downloading the right window builder. I had 3.7 instead of 4.3! so I think it was a compatibility issue